# Differences between Device Gateway and MQTT broker in AWS IoT

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, aws-iot

I'm studying AWS IoT architecture and I don't understand if there are differences between device gateway and mqtt broker. It seems that in AWS IoT architecture, functions of mqtt broker are performed by the device gateway. Is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it seems the same to me. Apparently, they are talking about "Gateway to the cloud" which is different from the usual IoT terminology for gateway which connects sensors to the interent and works as a producer of messages.

Regarding the broker, they seem have a more complicated architecture than a simple broker which forwards the messages based on topics (hence the name "rules engine").

I think you should consider that they are talking about a general architecture for all protocols rather a single one as, for example, the usual publisher-broker-subscriber architecture discussed here for MQTT protocol:
https://www.cloudmqtt.com/docs.html